# Image/Dialog place over rest of UI

Tags: android

I have an activity which contains a button in the bottom right of the screen.

On its click, I want to show the image (Like in red below) placed over rest of the UI in activity.

And there is a text written inside this image (myText) which is also clickable.

How can I position/place the image in red over of the activity.
And how can I make the text inside clickable.

I guess this can be done via Dialog, but not really sure.

Thank You

[image]

Comment: Can't you use a relative layout for the positioning of your red image? You could make it unvisible and not active and change these conditions on button click.

Answer (score 0):

you can overlapping views using FrameLayout  and position your image above your button when button clicked you can set your image visible and verse

take look on good tutorial about views overlapping

http://www.christianpeeters.com/android-tutorials/android-tutorial-overlay-with-user-instructions/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this my using [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html). See below links

http://mrbool.com/how-to-implement-popup-window-in-android/28285
http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/05/06/how-to-create-popups-in-android/

It will look something like this. You can change popup background and layout.

If the button is at bottom of the screen the popup will appear above the button as you indicated in your image.

[image]